# How to parse a regular text file in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

As far as I know/can find, there are two ways to do this.

1. State machine (as per
   [Best way to parse a dynamic text list in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325337/best-way-to-parse-a-dynamic-text-list-in-php))
2. Exploding it on newlines `explode("\n", $data)`

Given you have a record based (one line per record) text file with specific rules. Characters 1 to 2 give you the year in yy format, characters 3 to 4 give you the month in mm format.. charachters 70 to 72 give you some x paramater.

For CSV we have `str_getcsv()` but I don't think there's anything for text files as such.

My personal preference would be the simple newlines option. Thoughts?

The text file looks like this:

```
14 5 12466 3202313 710101010 31  7  9  5  3  4  4  4  4  50.21
14 5 22466 41317 7 7 7 3 3 7 19  5  6  3  3  3  2  2  3  30.10
14 5 32466 5 7 7 3 7 3172727 29  3  3  2  3  2  6 12 12  50.21
14 5 42466 62337332330231713 60  9 22 18  9 15  9  6  5 120.73
14 5 52466 71327202020202320 49  5 12  7  7  7  7  9  7  80.42
14 5 62466 8 3 7 7 7 3 3 3 3 11  2  3  3  3  2  2  2  2  20.00
14 5 72466 9 0 0 0 310 3 720 13  0  0  0  2  4  2  3  7  20.00
14 5 82466102333334320333037 76  9 18 18 32  7 18 15 22 170.94
14 5 924661130172017 7 3 010 31 15  6  7  6  3  2  0  4  50.21
14 51024661220301310 7 32327 40  7 15  5  4  3  2  9 12  70.42
14 5112466134330172713172027 58 32 15  6 12  5  6  7 12 120.73
14 5122466142320202320101717 45  9  7  7  9  7  4  6  6  70.31
14 51324661510131310 7 7 720 26  4  5  5  4  3  3  3  7  40.10
14 5142466161710 3 72317 717 30  6  4  2  3  9  6  3  6  50.21
14 51524661710101313 7101313 27  4  4  5  5  3  4  5  5  40.21
14 5162466181713101020201710 35  6  5  4  4  7  7  6  4  50.21
14 51724661913 7 3 7 3 3 3 3 13  5  3  2  3  2  2  2  2  30.00
14 518246620171310 717201013 32  6  5  4  3  6  7  4  5  50.21
14 5192466211013101013131020 30  4  5  4  4  5  5  4  7  50.21
14 520246622 7 7101010 7 3 3 17  3  3  4  4  4  3  2  2  30.10
14 521246623 7 3 3 3 0 3 3 7  9  3  2  2  2  0  2  2  3  20.00
14 5222466241010109999999999     4  4  4
```

Some rules for each record/line:

```
 1- 2 i2 yy, last two digits of year 
 3- 4 i2 mm, month (1-12) 
 5- 6 i2 dd, day of month (1-31) 

 7-10 i4 Bartels solar rotation number - a sequence of 27-day 
 intervals counted continuously from February 8, 1832 
11-12 i2 Number of day within the Bartels 27-day cycle 

13-28 8i2 3-hourly Kp indices (0-3, 3-6, 6-9, 9-12, 12-15, 
 15-18, 18-21, 21-24 UT) 
29-31 i3 Daily Kp sum, expressed to the nearest third of a unit 
 (supplied only for tradition, use Ap scientific 
 purposes!) 

32-55 8i3 3-hourly ap indices (0-3, 3-6, 6-9, 9-12, 12-15, 
 15-18, 18-21, 21-24 UT) 
56-58 i3 Ap equivalent daily amplitude -
```

Comment: If your data is as regular as you suggest then a regular expression would break it down very nicely. Edit: now that you've added some sample data I'd go with a regex.

Comment: No need for regex. Just explode on space and you have all the fields you need

Comment: You can still use functions like fgetcsv() just change the delimiter to a single space or a tab '\t'

Comment: The data is not provided by me and is given as is. I'm not entirely sure, but I don't think space-delimited is an option. That's why they have made rules based on character. I will add some of the rules to make it clear.

The downvote and close, could you comment why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this text format doesn't seem to have any delimiters, apart from newlines, I would read it line by line and use `substr` to get the fields from it. Regular expressions or CSV readers won't do the trick, since there is no delimiter. Well, Regular expressions would technically be possible, since you can also specify wildcards and a specific number of repetitions, but in the end it doesn't add much value.

So just read a line into `$line`, and parse it by getting a number of characters:

```
$year = trim(substr($line, 0, 2));
$month = trim(substr($line, 2, 2));
// etc.
```

It might seem cumbersome, but you can wrap this in a neat function, like this:

```
function getIntField($line, $start, $length);
{
  return (int)trim(substr($line, $start, $length));
}
```

If you take it a step further, you can make a field definition in an array to help you read the file:

```
$fields = array(
  'year' => array(0, 2, 'int'),
  'month' => array(2, 2, 'int'),
  'day' => array(4, 2, 'int'),
  'hour' => array(6, 2, 'int'),
  'amount' => array(8, 5, 'float')
);
```

Then, you can read a field like this:

```
function getField($line, $field)
{
  $fields = .... field def goes here (or use global or class variable).

  // Get the proper field definition for the field. (You can add some 
  // checking to see whether it exists.
  $def = fields[$field];

  // Read the specified part (start, length are in the field definition).
  $value = trim(substr($line, $def[0], $def[1]));

  // In my example, the third parameter of the definition is the type.
  switch ($def[2])
  {
    case 'int': return (int)$value;
    case 'float': return (float)$value;
  }

  // Not returned as a specific type? Then, just return the string.
  return $value;
}
```

If you wrap such a function in a class, then it should be very easy to have a class that handles the file access, and internally keeps track of the current line. Then you can just write a piece of code like this:

```
$amount = 0;
$file = new FixedLengthRecordFile($filePath);

while ($file->readLine())
{
  $amount += $file->getField('amount');
}

echo 'Total amount in file: ' . $amount;
```

If you like, you can even use the magic `__get` method to wrap the getter. That way, you can write:

```
$amount += $file->amount;
```

instead of

```
$amount += $file->getField('amount');
```

Anyway, that's probably how I would do it if I cannot find an out-of-the-box class that already does that for me. But I don't think there is.

Comment: Yeah, I was already beginning to use `substr()`. And like you say, it's possible with regex, but the question is whether it's worth it. At the moment I'm not doing anything with the types yet (the documentation does talk about it) so I'll make it even simpler than you suggested, but I like this approach.